# Android GoogleAnalytics v3 - TrackPageView

Tags: android, webview, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In the Android GoogleAnalytics API v1 is the `GoogleAnalyticsTracker` class where you can start trackPageView.

I don't find these in v3. Do you know the equivalent? **I want to track a webview like the javascript does in the browser.**

Or do you know how I can enable the javascript part in the HTML in the webview. Even if I enable Cookies and do `webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`, the page gets not tracked.

Comment: No one knows the answer? Had no one the same issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript in the webview works as it should. You have to set webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true) and webView.loadUrl("...").

My problem was that the app didn't use loadUrl(...), but loadDataWithBaseURL(...) (HTML content as String) which does not execute JavaScript.